# retrieve MenuItem app:showAsAction="always" info programatically

Tags: android

I'm coloring programmatically menu items. However, I would like to color only items that are visible on toolbar `app:showAsAction="always"`

How to retrieve that information programmatically? For some reason, I can't find it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly do you want to check if that item is displayed on toolbar?

Comment: yes, exactly. I've just found the solution...

Comment: Cool.. happy coding..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the solution. I've written this Kotlin extension

```
val MenuItem.showAsActionFlag: Int
    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    get() {
        this as MenuItemImpl
        return when {
            requiresActionButton() -> MenuItemImpl.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
            requestsActionButton() -> MenuItemImpl.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM
            showsTextAsAction() -> MenuItemImpl.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT
            else -> MenuItemImpl.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER
        }
    }
```

Now, I can check it like:

```
if (item.showAsActionFlag == SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS)
```